# BinarySearchingTree - dll(generic) , somehow my items can't be added to my adt

Tags: java, generics, adt, doubly-linked-list

I am wandering what i have done wrong, could anyone help me please? I am trying to make a generic BST, with DDL(doubly linked list) data structure. The thing is my ADT is initalisated since my `isEmpty` method  works, but my `public addNewElement` which sues `private insert` do not work. Any help and advices are welcome.

Interface:

```
public interface SortedSetBST <type> extends Iterable<type>{
            void addNewElement(Comparable<type> newElement);

    }
```

ADT:

```
package adt;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Iterator;

import interfaces.SortedSetBST;
import exceptions.*;

public class BinarySearchTree <type> implements SortedSetBST<type> {
    BinaryNode <type> root;
    int size;

    @Override
    public void addNewElement(Comparable  <type>  newElement) {
         insert(newElement, root);  
    }

protected BinaryNode  <type> insert( Comparable <type> x, BinaryNode <type>  t ) {
   if( t == null )
       t = new BinaryNode( x );
   else if( x.compareTo( t.element ) < 0 )
       t.left = insert( x, t.left );
   else if( x.compareTo( t.element ) > 0 )
       t.right = insert( x, t.right );
   else
       throw new DuplicateItemException( x.toString( ) );  // Duplicate
   return t;
}
class BinaryNode<type> {
    type element;      // The data in the node
    BinaryNode<type> left;         // Left child
    BinaryNode<type> right;        // Right child

    // Constructors
    BinaryNode( type theElement ) {
        element = theElement;
        left = right = null;
    }   
}
```

class App

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println("   Main:");
        BinarySearchTree <String> db = new BinarySearchTree<String>();

        if(db.isEmpty() == true){
            System.out.println(".db empty!");
        }
        db.addNewElement("unu");
        db.addNewElement("doi");
        db.addNewElement("trei");
        System.out.println(db.getSize());
    }
}
```

output:

```
   Main:
.db empty!
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clear.

In "insert" you are checking if t is null. If this is the case, you initialize the *parameter* t with an instance of BinaryNode thinking you would also update root when it is first passed in being "null". But "null" is "null" in Java and not a C-style-address as you might think!

Then you return this parameter but the return value is lost in "addNewElement".

How to do this right:

```
if( t == null ) {
   if (root == null){
      root = new BinaryNode(x);
      return root;
   } else {
      t = new BinaryNode( x );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, newbie under construction here :)